# NodeJS request doesn't encode the entire form

Tags: json, node.js, node-request

The task is rather simple, I request the endpoint with POST request (`https://banana.com/endpoint/swap.php`), give it my form: `{ banana: ["China's Red", "Sweden's Gray"],  apples: [] }` and send it.
However, the Request module for NodeJS that I am using does not encode the empty array (in this case "apples") and if the endpoint doesn't receive the "apples" array, it returns an error - "Invalid JSON". I have tried doing this with already encoded strings and it works just fine. I am also unable to stringify my json and then use `encodeURI()`, as it will then give "bananas" and "apples" quotes around them, which will get encoded - needless to say, the endpoint doesn't like that either.

I'd really appreciate if somebody could at least point me in the right direction. As I am unsure on how to proceed with this, without creating some awful spaghetti code.

Comment: just pointing out, you might need a comma before apples

Comment: @hairmot Sorry, it was just a typo in the post :p

Comment: try to add an empty string to apples array ===> apples: [""]

Comment: @WejdDAGHFOUS Just tried it, unfortunately it doesn't work. I'm guessing it checks if all of the supplied values are genuine and exist.

Answer (score 0):

```
data = { banana: ["China's Red", "Sweden's Gray"], apples: [] }   
result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))  .
```

You wouldn't get double around banana and apple and if you need to access then access it

```
console.log(result.banana)
console.log(result.apple)
```

So if you need to feed this result in post request then -

```
url = 'your url';
const options = {
  url: url,
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Accept-Charset': 'utf-8'
  },
  json: result
};
request.post(options, function (err, response, body) {
// do something with your data
})
```

Let me know if this works.